# Maximum call stack size exceeded with Node + Express + Angular + Angular-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-routing

I am starting a SPA with the following stack:

- Back-end:

  - NodeJS + Express
- Front-end:

  - Angular + Angular-route.
  - Twitter Bootstrap
  - Underscore

I have follow many tutorial with similar stack, and my files look like:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webportal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "pdonaire",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies" : {
    "express"    : "~4.7.2",
    "morgan"     : "~1.2.2",
    "method-override": "~2.1.2",
    "nodemon": "~1.7.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "angular": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.7",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets/js'));

var indexRoute = function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
};

app.get('/', indexRoute);
app.get('*', indexRoute);


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Webportal listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="WebPortal">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <title>WebPortal</title>
    <link href='/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/contact.js"></script>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('WebPortal', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/contacts', {
                templateUrl: 'contact.html',
                controller: "ContactCtrl"
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/contacts"
            });
    }
]);
```

**contact.js**

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
});
```

**contact.html**

`<h1>CONTACT</h1>`

Ok. Now I open a CMD and run `node index.js`. All works and when I open a Chrome tab with `http://localhost:3000` I get the following error in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8791:30)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8289:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:7680:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:7684:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:7555:30)
at link (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js:985:7)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8789:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8289:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:7680:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:7555:30) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12477(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9246invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8791nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7699controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8316update @ angular-route.js:935link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7680compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7684publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7555link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8789nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8289

angular.js:12477 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Object.ASTCompiler.compile (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:13310:10)
at Parser.parse (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14146:29)
at $parse (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14248:39)
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15989:16)
at update (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js:948:26)
at link (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js:900:9)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8789:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8289:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:7680:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:7684:13) <!-- ngView:  -->
```

Anyone knows what's happening? I don't see naything strange....

Thanks!!!

*EDIT 1*: Added contact.html code

*EDIT 2*: Added screenshot with Chrome Developer Tools console tab:

[image: Screenshot 1]

*EDIT 3: Added screenshot with Chrome Developer Tools Network tab:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. It looks that the problem is not a strange issue. The problem is that Angular does not find *.html* files, so it begins to loop (cause otherwise clause).

Mental note: Don't write *otherwise* clause.

Answer (score 2):

This error appears very often when you don't have a template related to the route that you're calling.

Simply add `contact.html` in your project.

Comment: I have contact.html in my project. It only shows a title `<h1>CONTACT</h1>` for test it

Comment: Nope... I've added a screenshot where you can see the error :)

Comment: And to be 100% sure - in `Networking` tab there are no errors ?

Comment: Everything is fine... I have added another screenshot

Answer (score 0):

What is your template engine?  I had a similar issue with handlebars (.hbs) where the layout.hbs was being called in an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't use any template engine. Is HTML from scratch :D. The problem was related with angular routing. Angular didn't find the *.html* file, so it redirects to default URL. There, it did not find the .html too, so it redirects to default URL, ..... An infinite loop

Comment: yeah, I had the same problem using .hbs, it was a biache to debug.

Comment: The issue here is the express.static directive, it kind of mess up the dir root reference for the entire project......You might want to create a valid express.static directive for your view path.